# Scala: Unspecified value parameter error when trying to create binary tree using fold on sequence of elements

Tags: scala, binary-tree, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to write a binary tree in scala. Here are my definitions

```
sealed trait Tree[+T]
final object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]
final case class Leaf[A](value: A) extends Tree[A]
final case class Branch[A](elem: A, left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]


object BinaryTree {

  def insert[ A : Ordering] (t : Tree[A])(implicit elem : A): Tree[A] = {
    val order = implicitly[Ordering[A]]
    t match {
      case Empty => Leaf(elem)
      case Leaf(x) if (elem == x) => t
      case Leaf(x) if (order.lt(elem, x)) => new Branch(elem, Empty, new Leaf(x))
      case Leaf(x)  => new Branch(elem, new Leaf(x), Empty)
      case Branch(x, left, right) if (elem == x) => t
      case Branch(x, left, right) if (order.lt(elem, x)) => new Branch(x, insert(left), right)
      case Branch(x, left, right) =>   new Branch(x, left, insert(right))
    }
  }

  def apply[A: Ordering](as: A*): Tree[A] =
    as.tail.foldLeft[Tree[A]](Leaf(as.head))((t, elem) => BinaryTree.insert(t)(elem))
}
```

In my BinaryTree.apply method I get the following error

```
"Unspecified value parameters: elem : A"
```

Not sure what that is supposed to mean or what I am missing. Can anyone please help me out

Comment: If I remove implicit keyword from insert and write it as  insert[ A : Ordering] (t : Tree[A])(elem : A) it seems to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **context bound** and implicit parameters, all the parameters including context bound forms single set of params, the set being in the end.

So your `insert` signature:

```
def insert[A: Ordering] (t: Tree[A])(implicit elem: A)
```

is similar to:

```
def insert(t: Tree[A])(implicit o: Ordering[A], elem: A)
```

It means that you should either not pass `o` and `elem` parameters when calling `insert` or pass them both.